# xcode - Could not locate device support file

Tags: xcode

Could not locate device support files.

[image]

How to solve this issue?

This is question has the correct answer, the other doesn't.

Answer (score 1):

This is because the ios on your iphone is not compatible with xcode.

Solution: Update Xcode to the latest version.

If you can't find new xcode update in the app store. You will need to go to apple developer website and download xcode directly from there. Sometime Apple doesn't push latest xcode to the app store. Yes they are lousy.